# Does OnSubmit will wait OnBlur to execute before?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have two input forms email and password with `onBlur` to validate them and a Button for `onSubmit`. My question is, if email form `onBlur` executed when I start typing on password form, how about that password form when I'll click directly next the `onSubmit` button, isn't? That means (because Javascript and `setState()` are asynchronous) the `onBlur` may not be executed first or at least `onSubmit` may start its logic execution before finishing the `onBlur` logic of Password form, so a state in `onSubmit` may have wrong data cause it didn't wait password form `onBlur`? (I really hate that fact in web development)

When I look at `console.log` I see it respected password `onBlur`, `setState()` execution and waited for its callback, but I'm not sure if it will work the same every time. (`console.log(Blur)` line is only in password `onBlur` not in email for testing)

[image: example]

Edit : I tested again and it appears that sometimes if password form has an error the submit Button wont execute any line in `onSubmit` code, so I need sometimes after correcting password error to click twice on Submit button to make `onSubmit` code executed. How to deal with that conflict?

[image: example 2]

Code:

Form:

```
 const SignInForm = (props) => {
    let enabledOrDisabled = props.signInFormCanEvent ? false : 'disabled';
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>Welcome to ToDo</h1>
            <form onSubmit={props.signInSubmitHandler} className={style.signInForm}>
                <span className={style.userFormsErrors}>{props.userNotFoundError}</span>
                <div className={style.signInFormImportantElements}>
                    <span className={style.userFormsErrors}>{props.userEmailError}</span>
                    <input
                        name="userEmail"
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="email"
                        value={props.currentUserEmailText}
                        className={style.signInText}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            props.signInOnChangeHandler(e);
                        }}
                        onBlur={(e) => props.signInOnBlurHandler(e)}
                        disabled={enabledOrDisabled}
                    />
                    <span className={style.userFormsErrors}>{props.userPasswordError}</span>
                    <input
                        name="userPassword"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="password"
                        value={props.currentUserPasswordText}
                        className={style.signInText}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            props.signInOnChangeHandler(e);
                        }}
                        onBlur={(e) => props.signInOnBlurHandler(e)}
                        disabled={enabledOrDisabled}
                    />
                    <label>
                        Remember me
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            name="rememberMe"
                            onChange={(e) => props.signInOnChangeHandler(e)}
                            disabled={enabledOrDisabled}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" className={style.signInSubmit} disabled={enabledOrDisabled} />
                </div>
                <div className={style.signInLinks}>
                    <a href="#">Forget Password</a>
                    {/*<a href="#">Create Account</a>*/}
                    <input type="button" value="SignUp" onClick={props.signUpLinkHandler} />
                </div>
            </form>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

onBlur :

```
signInOnBlurHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    let tmpErrors = { ...this.state.signInErrors };
    switch (name) {
        case 'userEmail':
            tmpErrors.userEmailError = validEmailRegex.test(value) ? '' : 'Email is not valid!';
            this.setState({ signInErrors: tmpErrors });
            break;
        case 'userPassword':
            tmpErrors.userPasswordError = value.length >= 8 ? '' : 'Password must be at least 8 characters long!';
            this.setState({ signInErrors: tmpErrors }, () => {
                console.log('blur');
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

onSubmit :

```
signInSubmitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submit');
    let signInErrorsTmp = { ...this.state.signInErrors };
    signInErrorsTmp.userNotFoundError = '';
    this.setState({ signInErrors: signInErrorsTmp }, () => {
        let canSubmit = true;
        for (let element in this.state.signInErrors) {
            if (this.state.signInErrors[element].length > 0) {
                canSubmit = false;
            }
        }
        if (canSubmit) {
            const config = {
                //crossDomain: true,
                withCredentials: true
            };
            axios
                .post(
                    'http://localhost/React_ToDo_APP/to-do/src/PHPFiles/UserSignIn.php',
                    this.state.signInUserInfo,
                    config
                )
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.status == 201) {
                        const tmpSignInUserInfo = { ...this.state.signInUserInfo };
                        tmpSignInUserInfo.currentUserEmailText = '';
                        tmpSignInUserInfo.currentUserPasswordText = '';
                        tmpSignInUserInfo.currentUserRememberMe = false;
                        this.setState({ signInUserInfo: tmpSignInUserInfo }, () => {
                            const signedInUserSessionDataTmp = { ...this.state.signedInUserSessionData };
                            signedInUserSessionDataTmp.userName = response.data.userName;
                            this.setState({ signedInUserSessionData: signedInUserSessionDataTmp }, () => {
                                this.setState({ isUserSignedIn: true }, () => {
                                    this.resetAndGetData();
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log('Error: ', error);
                    if (error.response.status == 401) {
                        let signInErrorsTmp = { ...this.state.signInErrors };
                        if (error.response.data.emailError.length > 0)
                            signInErrorsTmp.userEmailError = error.response.data.emailError;
                        if (error.response.data.passwordError.length > 0)
                            signInErrorsTmp.userPasswordError = error.response.data.passwordError;
                        if (
                            error.response.data.hasOwnProperty('userNotFoundError') &&
                            error.response.data.userNotFoundError.length > 0
                        )
                            signInErrorsTmp.userNotFoundError = error.response.data.userNotFoundError;
                        this.setState({ signInErrors: signInErrorsTmp });
                    }
                });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the below, so long as the form is submitted by a click, and not enter keydown, then onBlur handler should apply first, and onSubmit handler will receive correct state.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {

  state={
    value1:"",
    value2:"",
    validated1: '',
    validated2: ''
   }
   
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit", this.state);
  }
  
  handleBlur = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    this.setState({["validated" + target.id]: target.value.toUpperCase()})
    console.log("blur");
  }
  
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    
    this.setState({["value" + target.id]:target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} onBlur={this.handleBlur} value={this.state.value1} id="1"/>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} onBlur={this.handleBlur} value={this.state.value2} id="2"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks , but i tried again and i see there is some conflict there , for example if i had an error on password form and i corrected it the first click on Submit wont do nothing , so i need to click 2 times on it

Comment: can you make a snippet or codesandbox of your code?

Comment: sorry i dont know how to make a snippet here so i copied the code

Comment: I noticed you aren't passing console.log('blur') as a callback for your email validation setState (only the password validation setState).

Comment: yes i mentioned that , and in place of console.log("click") i changed it to "submit" to make it clear , my problem is moving from the last form (password) to click directly on Submit button thats why i dont need to log email form i have no problem with it except if its the one who has the error so the same thing may happen the first click on Submit button may have no effect it will just execute onBlur() of that form then i will need to click again to submit

Comment: i mean with error the validation , when i correct that form sometimes but not every time i need to click twice on Submit button to execute the code in onSubmit()

Comment: nothing is immediately jumping out as to why, but I'll take another look and let you know if I spot anything